# Spark how can I extract only Json data from a line

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a bunch of files with each line something like:

```
some random non json stuff here {"timestmap":21212121, "name":"John"}
```

I cannot read these files as json because of that random stuff there is just before the Json data.

What would be the best way to cleanup that random stuff in order to be able to load the Json data into a DF with proper column?.

The end goal is to have a final DF with only data where timestamp is between as certain date.

Comment: Read the whole line as a string, then remove everything before the first `"{"` (Assuming some random non json stuff doesn't contain any `{`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses

- `instr` to find occurence of the JSON curly braces `{` and `}`
- `substr` to get the substring between curly braces (the JSON text)

Then it uses `from_json` with a schema defining the expected JSON structure.

---

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, instr
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Expected JSON schema 
schema = StructType([StructField("timestmap", TimestampType()),
                     StructField("name", StringType())])
# Filtering and parsing
parsed = df.select(from_json(
                df.value.substr(instr(df.value, '{'), instr(df.value, '}')), 
                schema).alias("json"))

# Don't know if it's possible to do it in one step ...
parsed = parsed.select(F.col("json.timestmap").alias("timestmap"),
                       F.col("json.name").alias("name"))

parsed.printSchema()
parsed.show()
```

The result is

```
root
 |-- timestmap: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

+-------------------+----+
|          timestmap|name|
+-------------------+----+
|1970-09-03 12:15:21|John|
|1970-09-03 12:15:22| Doe|
+-------------------+----+
```

Example text file `random.txt` is

```
some random non json stuff here {"timestmap":21212121, "name":"John"}
some other random non json stuff here {"timestmap":21212122, "name":"Doe"}
```

Comment: Nice. In between I had also built a small solution with 'regex_extract' to extract what is between {}